# c# + db: there should be one row at least in data grid view else its give error on deleting last row

Tags: c#, database, datagridview

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HbrBx.png)

Actually when ever i try to delete last row of data grid view  it gives that error which is shown in picture but when i open form again that row has been deleted i don't know why is gives error during run time, i added tables programmably  not through side click on data gird view and add tables via data source. Any solution to avoid this error when I delete last row.

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("");
con.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;


cmd.CommandText = "DELETE FROM LIST WHERE M_iD='" +    
txtdelete.Text + "'";
string store = txtdelete.Text;

int k = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
if (!this.txtdelete.Text.Equals(""))
    {
        if (k > 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("deleted sucessfully");


        }
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("not deleted");
    }


txtdelete.Text = string.Empty;
display();
con.Close();
```

Comment: Please show us your code !

Comment: this is the code of delete when i click on button

Comment: i just hide the connection string :P

Comment: have you tried debugging of your code? which line of code throws the error you are refering to. ?

Comment: What's the code inside the function `display()`?

Comment: __Do not__ call a `DataGridView`a `GridView`!! This is wrong and confusing and and bound to get wrong answers wasting everybody's time.. Always call things by their __right__ name!